# How to view one user data into a TextView from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is my main page code to retrieve data:

```
btnprof.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
                {
                    show("ERROR", "NOTHING");
                    return;
                }else
                {
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext())
                    {
                        buffer.append("ID :" + cursor.getString(0) + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + "Username :" + " " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n");
                    }
                    show("USER PROFILE",buffer.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Then this is my database code:

```
    public Cursor ShowData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return result;
    }
```

This is the snap of the output:

[image]

So with this code, all the data are viewed instead of only one data.
How can I make it so that only one data is shown?

Comment: how do you want to get only 1 data by user id or user name? here you write a code for retriving all data

Comment: i want to get data by user id and i want to view all the information of the selected id. i know my db code retrieve all data but i dont know how to retrieve one data only

Answer (score 0):

you may change your query like below

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+" WHERE id = ?", new String[] {"3"});
```

just pass id value which you want to get

Comment: so from ur answer, i declare which data i want to view from database. how about i enter the id that i want to view in editText then view it once i click on the btnprof ? im sorry i just dont know how to do it.

Comment: what you have to do. explain it in detail.